# Search selected text and show all occurrence of it in current (all other buffers) in emacs?

Tags: emacs

So in notepad++ I can select text, hit C-f, then, if I need to look for occurrence of selection in all opened files, i hit M-o and get nice clickable list with navigating to occurrence option. Or if I need list only for current file I point mouse to “Find all in current document” button do a click and get same nice clickable list only for currently active file. So is it possible to do exact thing in emac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement that functionality with the following lisp function:

```
(defun occur-selection ()
  (interactive)                   
  (when (region-active-p)         
    (let (deactivate-mark)      
      (occur (regexp-quote (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end)))))))
```

If you put that code in your `~/.emacs` file together with the follwing line:

```
(global-set-key [(meta o)] 'occur-selection)
```

you should be able to select some text, hit <kbd>M-o</kbd> and get a list of all occurrences of the selected text displayed in a separate buffer.

User <kbd>M-g n</kbd> and <kbd>M-g p</kbd> do cycle through the matching lines in the original buffer.

Note, however, that  multiple occurrences in a single line are not distinguished.

Comment: This is what i need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default, Emacs has <kbd>M-x occur</kbd> which work similar but slightly differently. It allows you to specify a regular expression, all matches of which in the current buffer will be displayed and hyperlinked.

If your focus is more on navigation than on highlighting all matches of a search term, there might be an external alternative that could help you.

Emacs' original philosophy is not built around user interface metaphors such as clicking with a mouse, it comes from a keyboard only background. If you're interested in this approach, you might want to have a look at the [Avy](https://github.com/abo-abo/avy) package for Emacs. It lets you quickly jump to one of multiple occurrences of a word.

Check out the excellent Emacs Rocks episode "Jumping Around" to see a precursor of Avy (called ace-jump-mode) in action: http://emacsrocks.com/e10.html

Comment: You can navigate with `occur`.  Use `next-error` and `previous-error`; find the keys they're bound to with `C-h w`.

Comment: It allows you to specify a regular expression

Comment: It allows you to specify a regular expression
-------------------------------------------------
The point is not type whole thing but just select and search. If select something with for example * in it, it will mess whole thing and you have to \ it. Bad. Actually in emacs I like ability to incremental replace and named bookmarks (it better then f2 bookmark in notepad++) but this fingers flexibility it require puzzled me little.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing with the helm package.
Emacs will search the word the cursor/"point" is on (you
don't need to highlight it).

To make helm search in all open files/buffers, use:

> M-x helm-multi-swoop-all

To make helm search only in file/buffer you're currently in, use:

> M-x helm-swoop

Press the ENTER key to drop into the selected file at the
selected line.

To bind these functions to the same key-comboes, you'd need
this in your .emacs:

> ```
> (global-set-key (kbd "M-o") 'helm-multi-swoop-all)
> (global-set-key (kbd "C-f") 'helm-swoop)
> ```

NB
Helm is hosted in the MELPA repository.

HTH,
Michael